# Equivalence relation question $A = \{ 1,2,3,4\} , R=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\} $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to show that $A$ is Equivalence relation
$$A = \{ 1,2,3,4\} , R=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\} $$ 
1) I need to add to $R$ more terms that $R$ will be equivalence relation?
2) I need to show that $R$ is

1. $(a,a)\in A \rightarrow$ Reflexivity
2. $(a,b) \in A , (b,a) \in A \rightarrow $ Symmetry
3. $(a,b) \in A , (a,c) \in A \rightarrow (a,c)\in A $ Transitivity

for (1.) I see that there is term $(1,1)$, its enough to say that $R$ is relexivity? or I need that all the combinations like $(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)$ will be in R?

for (2.) I need only 1 example? or all the combinations? 
for (3.) the same as (2.)
I want to understand it, so I need some advice.
In addition to how I write it in a formal way.
Thanks!

Comment: You should note the difference between 'exists', and 'for all'. For (1) $R$ is reflexive $\Leftrightarrow (a, a) \in R, \forall a \in A$. i.e, you have to check FOR ALL $a \in A$, is it true that $(a; a) \in R$? Not just check 1, or 2 elements like that, but ALL!! For (2), it says that WHENEVER $(a; b) \in R$, then $(b; a)$ must be an element of $R$ too. The same holds for (3). Btw, it's not $A$ is the equivalent relation, but $R$. $A$ is just any set that a relation is defined on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not reflexive since $\,(3,3)\;,\;(4,4)\notin R\,$

You can though take $\,A':=\{1,2\}\,$ instead of the whole $\,A\,$ and then you get an equivalence rel. on $\,A'\,$ ...

Comment: its enough to say that $R = \{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}$ to be equivalence rel?

Comment: Yes, that's an equiv. relation on $\,A\,$

Answer (score 0):

For $R$ to be reflexive on the given set $A$ it must be the case that all of $(1,1),(2,2), (3,3), (4,4)$ are elements of $R$, not just $(1,1)$. Therefore, $R$ , as a relation of the set $A$, is not reflexive. Consequently it is also not an equivalence relation on $A$.

For $R$ to be symmetric you need to show that for all $x,y\in A$, if $(x,y)\in R$, then $(y,x)\in R$. This is clearly the case for $R$, just by inspecting its elements. A similar remark holds for transitivity.